# Turning on "Increase contrast" reduces contrast of tag and window button colors (Big Sur/Monterey)

Tags: big-sur, monterey, color, accessibility, finder-tag

I recently upgraded a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) I use at work from macOS Catalina 10.15.7 to Monterey 12.3.1.

I have "Increase contrast" enabled (under *System Preferences > Accessibility > Display*) as I prefer to have obvious edges around UI elements ("Show toolbar button shapes" adds faint edges to buttons, but not other UI elements).

After upgrading to Monterey, I noticed that the colors of Finder tags and the close/minimize/zoom buttons in each window's title bar have changed: when using the "Light" appearance (selected in *System Preferences > General*), they're much darker than they were on Catalina (e.g., the yellow Finder tag is brown).

[image]

When using the "Dark" appearance, the window buttons look fine, but some of the Finder tags are too bright (e.g., the purple tag is light gray).

[image]

In both cases, the issue with the colors of the Finder tags is less pronounced when a Finder window isn't selected.

If "Increase contrast" is turned off, the colors return to normal; for example, when using the "Light" appearance with "Increase contrast" disabled, the colors are "normal":

[image]

Overall, the colors are (ironically) harder to differentiate when "Increase contrast" is turned on; this wasn't an issue in Catalina.

I wasn't able to find much documentation of this issue online; it appears to have been reported [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253509565) for Monterey and indirectly in [this forum thread discussing UI changes made in Big Sur](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/big-surs-white-on-white-ui-makes-increase-contrast-option-attractive.2266989/).

Is this a known bug with Big Sur/Monterey? Is there a workaround to make the colors more distinct/"normal" when "Increase contrast" is enabled?

*Note: I don't actually use tags, but given the current lack of documentation regarding this problem (and the fact that it affects accessibility) I thought it was worth posting this question as there are undoubtedly users who use do use tags and who also prefer (or require) the improved legibility of increased-contrast mode.*